# Cannot use EJB inside ManagedBean

Tags: jsf, netbeans, ejb

I have created an Enterprise Project with Netbeans, so there is a project for the EJB's and a project for the web components. I have this code for the EJB:

```
@Stateless
public class JosContentFacade extends AbstractFacade<JosContent> {

@PersistenceContext(unitName = "com.guiatic_GuiaTIC-ejb_ejb_1.0-SNAPSHOTPU")
private EntityManager em;

@Override
protected EntityManager getEntityManager() {
    return em;
}

public JosContentFacade() {
    super(JosContent.class);
}

}
```

and this code for the ManagedBean:

```
@Named(value = "showRelateds")
@RequestScoped
public class showRelateds {

@EJB
private JosContentFacade josContentFacade;

private String msg;

/**
 * Creates a new instance of showRelateds
 */
public showRelateds() {
}

public String getMsg() {
    msg = "MENSAJE DE PRUEBAS 3!!!";
    return msg;
}

public void setMsg(String msg) {
    this.msg = msg;
}

}
```

If I remove this line:

```
@EJB
private JosContentFacade josContentFacade;
```

The bean works properly, but with such line, it doesn't show me any error, but the bean doesn't work.

Comment: `the bean doesn't work` What do you mean by this?

Comment: Did you check the server log? If you happen to have sent a JSF ajax request, there's by default no feedback when an exception occurs. See also a.o. http://stackoverflow.com/q/27526753

Comment: Use interfaces for EJB. If you have different applications (different projects?) then use `@Remote` and inject (`@EJB`) it by interface. If you have everything in same JVM you can use `@Local` interface or `@LocalBean` without interface.