# XML Parsing Error: no element found Location: http://localhost:8081/web-app/pages/login.xhtml Line Number 1, Column 1: ^

Tags: jsf, xml-parsing, facelets

My `login.xhtml` starts with:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

I am using Java 8, JSF, Primefaces, Maven, Tomcat8.
I think that something is wrong with my configuration e.g. servlets and `web.xml`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> XML Parsing Error: no element found Location: [...] Line Number 1, Column 1

To the point, this exact error means that the webbrowser retrieved an entirely empty response while it is being instructed to interpret the response as XML, usually via the `Content-Type` header such as `application/xhtml+xml` or `application/xml`, or if absent, via the file extension in URL such as `.xhtml` or `.xml`.

Given that this happens while requesting a JSF login page, this strongly suggests that it contained a syntax/runtime error and that the webapp doesn't have error handling correctly configured. Apparently error pages themselves are also blocked behind a login/security constraint, causing the server being unable to present a "normal" error page with all exception detail and therefore return a completely empty response.

Your best bet is reading the server logs for the actual exception and/or running a debugger and/or creating a [JSF exception handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27526753/exception-handling-in-jsf-ajax-requests/27532827#27532827) which explicitly logs exceptions to server log (just in case you couldn't find exceptions and thus they appear to be swallowed). Once having the actual exception at hands, it's usually a matter of using the exception type + message + 1st line as keywords to find clues on the Internet.

Comment: Thank you a lot. I had an error in my tomcat output with my listener. I fixed it and it looks much better now.
Yes, you are right that I need to implement web app handling.

Answer (score -1):

**XML Parsing Error: no root element found**

The ERROR occurs when your client send a request like below:

```
curl -X GET --header 'Accept: application/json' 'http://192.168.1.249:9001/students/
```

you can see in header like 'Accept: application/json' this means the client only accept the server response in JSON format.

But Server produces a response type in XML content type and it will try to parse the XML to JSON. During this phase exception triggers.

**SOLUTION :**

Please change the response content type to application/json  or 
Change the request header to 'Accept: application/xml'.

Thanks.