# MyFaces swallows SystemEvent that contains a validation exception

Tags: jsf, jsf-2.2, myfaces

I am using Apache MyFaces 2.2.11 for my JSF Web Application (with PrimeFaces).

During the phase `PROCESS_VALIDATIONS(3)` the `ProcessValidationsExecutor` throws a `ContextAwarePropertyNotFoundException` that is caused by a simple `PropertyNotFoundException` *(javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Target Unreachable, 'recipientAddress' returned null)* during the `executePhase()`. The exception is then caught and `publishException()` is called. This calls the `publishEvent()` method of the `ApplicationImpl` class.

However, when trying to find the `SystemListenerEntry` that is responsible for publishing the event none is found. The `systemEventClass` at this point is **ExceptionQueuedEvent**. However, there is no entry for that key in the `_systemEventListenerClassMap`.

The maps contains only entries for:

- javax.faces.event.PreDestroyApplicationEvent
- javax.faces.event.PostConstructApplicationEvent
- javax.faces.event.PreRenderComponentEvent
- javax.faces.event.PreDestroyCustomScopeEvent
- javax.faces.event.PreDestroyViewMapEvent
- javax.faces.event.PostAddToViewEvent
- javax.faces.event.PostValidateEvent

Without having found a `SystemListenerEntry` the `publishEvent()` method simply returns and the exception is swallowed/lost. As a result, no validation errors are presented or even logged and the action method in my view bean is not called without getting any feedback.

Any ideas what the problem could be?

**EDIT:**
Using Mojarra, the exception is logged. Three times even!

```
17-May-2017 14:44:23.936 INFO [http-nio-8443-exec-5] com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl.processPartial javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: /views/panels/editable_address.xhtml @50,65 value="#{viewBean.shippingRequest.recipientAddress.contactPartner}": Target Unreachable, 'recipientAddress' returned null

17-May-2017 14:44:23.938 WARNING [http-nio-8443-exec-5] com.sun.faces.lifecycle.ProcessValidationsPhase.execute javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: /views/panels/editable_address.xhtml @50,65 value="#{viewBean.shippingRequest.recipientAddress.contactPartner}": Target Unreachable, 'recipientAddress' returned null

17-May-2017 14:44:23.947 SEVERE [http-nio-8443-exec-5] com.sun.faces.context.AjaxExceptionHandlerImpl.handlePartialResponseError javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: /views/panels/editable_address.xhtml @50,65 value="#{viewBean.shippingRequest.recipientAddress.contactPartner}": Target Unreachable, 'recipientAddress' returned null
```

Comment: Does it work with Mojarra? Does it work with an older MyFaces version? And I removed the PrimeFaces and Tomcat tag since these do not seem to be related. (unless you get it to work with a plain jsf on e.g. jboss with myfaces)

Comment: Thanks, I added the Mojarra output. I have not tried an older version of MyFaces yet.

Comment: What if you run in dev mode?

Comment: I am running in dev mode

Comment: This is during an ajax request, right? That event is normally to be dealt with an `ExceptionHandler`.

Comment: Yes. I just added `ajax="false"` to the `<p:commandButton`. Now the exception is presented on the myFaces error page. :) And in fact, this button is supposed to save the entity and submit the whole form so I guess I don't really want to use ajax anyway. Still, simply swallowing the exception when `ajax="true"` does not seem right.

Comment: Does this answer your question? http://stackoverflow.com/q/27526753