# JSF: malformedXML: During update: javax.faces.Resource not found

Tags: jsf, bootsfaces

I am using the **bootsFaces** library for my JSF web project. When I use page redirection with ajax I get a message: "JSF: malformedXML: During update: javax.faces.Resource not found"
The strange thing here is that the pages without the tag:  can still be used normally but not.
Can someone help me. Here is my code
**Student.xhtml**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:b="http://bootsfaces.net/ui">
    <h:head>
        <title>Facelet Title</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <ui:composition>
            <b:form>
                <b:dataTable value="#{studentController.getStudent()}" var="student" select="true">
                    <b:dataTableColumn value="#{student.id}" label="ID"/>
                    <b:dataTableColumn value="#{student.name}" label="TÊN"/>
                    <b:dataTableColumn value="#{student.department_name}" label="Phòng ban"/>
                    <b:dataTableColumn value="#{student.tot_cred}" label="Tín chỉ"/>
                </b:dataTable>
            </b:form>
        </ui:composition>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

**StudentController.java**

```
package Controller;
import Define.SQLDefine;
import Model.Student;
import Model.Model;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.faces.bean.ApplicationScoped;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.view.ViewScoped;
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class StudentController extends Model {
    public ArrayList<Student> getStudent() {
        ArrayList<Student> students = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            PreparedStatement stmt = connection.prepareCall(SQLDefine.getSQL(3));
            ResultSet resStudent = stmt.executeQuery();
            if (resStudent.next()) {
                resStudent.beforeFirst();
                while (resStudent.next()) {
                    students.add(
                            new Student(
                                    resStudent.getInt(1),
                                    resStudent.getString(2),
                                    resStudent.getString(3),
                                    resStudent.getInt(4)
                            ));
                }
            }
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(StudentController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            System.out.println("29111999: " + ex.getMessage());
        }
        return students;
    }
}
```

**Home.xhtml**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
    xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:b="http://bootsfaces.net/ui">
    <h:head>
        <title>Home Controller</title>
        <link type="text/css" href="./css/style.css"/>
        <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="../img/favicon.ico" />
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <!-- Header -->
        <ui:insert name="Header">
            <ui:include src="include/Header.xhtml"/>
        </ui:insert>
        <!-- Content -->
        <b:container class="MainContent">
            <ui:insert name="content">
                <ui:include src="#{homeBean.page}"/>
            </ui:insert>
        </b:container>
        <!-- UI -->
        <ui:insert>
            <ui:include src="include/UserModal.xhtml"/>
        </ui:insert>
    </h:body>
    <!-- Script JS -->
    <script>
        $.blockUI.defaults.css.width = '20%';
        $.blockUI.defaults.css.left = '40%';
        $.blockUI.defaults.css.height = '5em';
        $.blockUI.defaults.css.borderRadius = '10px';
        $.blockUI.defaults.overlayCSS.opacity = 0.5;
        $.blockUI.defaults.message = '<div style="padding-top:1em"><img src="../img/pikachu.gif" alt="Wait" style="width: 60px; heifgt: 60px"/></div>';
    </script>
</html>
```

**Header.xhtml**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:b="http://bootsfaces.net/ui"
      xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core">
    <h:head>
        <title>Header</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <ui:composition>
            <h:form>
                <b:navBar brand="TelSoft" brandHref="#">
                    <b:navbarLinks>
                        <b:navLink
                            href="#"
                            value="Home"
                            icon-awesome="fa-home"
                            update="@form @(.MainContent)"
                            onclick="ajax:homeBean.setPage('include/Home.xhtml')"/>
                        <b:navLink
                            href="#"
                            value="Import course"
                            icon-awesome="fa-download"
                            update="@form @(.MainContent)"
                            onclick="ajax:homeBean.setPage('include/ImportCourse.xhtml')"/>
                        <b:dropMenu value="Quản lý" iconAwesome="fas fa-cog">
                            <b:navLink
                                href="#"
                                value="Sinh viên"
                                icon-awesome="fa-child"
                                update="@form @(.MainContent)"
                                onclick="ajax:homeBean.setPage('include/Student.xhtml')"/>
                            <b:navLink
                                href="#"
                                value="Giáo viên"
                                icon-awesome="fa-female"
                                update="@form @(.MainContent)"
                                onclick="ajax:homeBean.setPage('include/Teacher.xhtml')"/>
                            <b:navLink 
                                href="#"
                                value="Thư viện"
                                icon-awesome="fa-book"
                                update="@form @(.MainContent)"
                                onclick="ajax:homeBean.setPage('include/Library.xhtml')"/>
                        </b:dropMenu>
                    </b:navbarLinks>
                    <b:navbarLinks pull="right" class="text-center">
                        <li>
                            <a href="#userModal" data-toggle="modal">
                                <b:iconAwesome name="fa-user"/>
                                Xin chào: #{homeBean.fullName}
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    </b:navbarLinks>
                </b:navBar>
            </h:form>
        </ui:composition>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

Comment: You'll likely find an exception in your server log.

Comment: See this Q/A:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27526753/exception-handling-in-jsf-ajax-requests