# Returning invalid view from JSF action method shows warning in the facelet, but how could I detect it earlier?

Tags: jsf

I have a JSF 2.3 application.
In my LoginBean, the username and password entered by the user are varified and then the user is redirected to the URL initially inquired: for example if the user inquires:

http://myhostname/admin/manage.jsf

then because every resource under http:///admin requires authentication, the user is first redirected to the logon view, something like

http://myhostname/login/login.jsf

and then, upon successful authentication, they are redirected to their initially inquired URL  (in this case, the first URL above)

However, if the initially inquired URL  is a view that does not exist, i.e.

http://myhostname/admin/nonExisting.jsf

after the user gets authenticated, nothing happens: He / she is neither shown an error page, nor an erroneous log entry is made in the logs. Just the user remains on the login page.

How could I solve this?!

I added  an error handling in the facelet like this:

```
<p:growl id="messages" autoUpdate="true" showDetail="true" />
```

and then, for the logon button:

```
<p:commandButton action="#{loginBean.login}" value="Log In" update="@form"/>
```

Now, when a non-existing view is returned, I do see the warning message:

[image]

but how coul I handle it earlier?

Comment: So, you're using ajax to login, and there's no exception handler for ajax requests?

Comment: nope, I am using form submit like this:                                  <p:commandButton action="#{loginBean.login}"  value="Log In"/>

Comment: So you don't know that **by default** the PrimeFaces `p:commandButton` is doing ajax https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/button/commandButton.xhtml?  An [mcve]  would have shown this.

Comment: No, I did not know. However replacing p:commandButton by h:commandButton does not change anything

Comment: Please let me know what "the normal" behavior should be - shall I get an error, a HTTP 404 or what?

Comment: this problem, and its solution are described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27526753/exception-handling-in-jsf-ajax-requests

Comment: with a plain `h:commandButton` you should get an error... Certainly if you run your application in development mode.