# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: null source on cell editing on data table

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jboss, xhtml

I have a data table in my xhtml file. The data table is using live scroll with lazy loading. The data table also have some editable fields (cell editing). after doing some scrolling and loading more rows, when I edit the cell having selectOneMenu, it throws following exception:

```
8:42:12,775 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/nextwrapper].[Faces Servlet]] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-4) Servlet.service() for servlet Faces Servlet threw exception: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl.createPartialResponseWriter(PartialViewContextImpl.java:441) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl.access$300(PartialViewContextImpl.java:71) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl$DelayedInitPartialResponseWriter.getWrapped(PartialViewContextImpl.java:582) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
    at javax.faces.context.PartialResponseWriter.startDocument(PartialResponseWriter.java:115) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
    at org.primefaces.context.PrimePartialResponseWriter.startDocument(PrimePartialResponseWriter.java:160) [primefaces-5.3.jar:5.3]
    at com.sun.faces.context.AjaxExceptionHandlerImpl.handlePartialResponseError(AjaxExceptionHandlerImpl.java:199) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.context.AjaxExceptionHandlerImpl.handle(AjaxExceptionHandlerImpl.java:123) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
    at com.nextcontrol.utility.CustomExceptionHandler.handle(CustomExceptionHandler.java:40) [classes:]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:119) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.doPhase(RestoreViewPhase.java:116) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:593) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:329) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:100) [primefaces-5.3.jar:5.3]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:275) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:153) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:368) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:671) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:930) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
```

the actual exception is as follows (using [Exception handling in JSF ajax requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27526753/exception-handling-in-jsf-ajax-requests/27532827))

```
18:42:12,741 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-4) java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: null source
18:42:12,741 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-4)      at java.util.EventObject.<init>(EventObject.java:56)
18:42:12,742 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-4)      at javax.faces.event.SystemEvent.<init>(SystemEvent.java:71)
18:42:12,746 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-4)      at javax.faces.event.ComponentSystemEvent.<init>(ComponentSystemEvent.java:73)
18:42:12,748 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-4)      at javax.faces.event.PostRestoreStateEvent.<init>(PostRestoreStateEvent.java:73)
18:42:12,749 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-4)      at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.deliverPostRestoreStateEvent(RestoreViewPhase.java:271)
18:42:12,750 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-4)      at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.execute(RestoreViewPhase.java:257)
18:42:12,752 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-4)      at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
18:42:12,755 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-4)      at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.doPhase(RestoreViewPhase.java:116)
18:42:12,756 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-4)      at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
18:42:12,756 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-4)      at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:593)
18:42:12,757 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-4)      at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:329)
18:42:12,758 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-4)      at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248)
18:42:12,759 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-4)      at org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:100)
18:42:12,760 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-4)      at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280)
18:42:12,763 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-4)      at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248)
18:42:12,765 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-4)      at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:275)
18:42:12,766 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-4)      at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161)
18:42:12,767 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-4)      at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:153)
18:42:12,768 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-4)      at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155)
18:42:12,768 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-4)      at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
18:42:12,769 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-4)      at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
18:42:12,770 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-4)      at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:368)
18:42:12,771 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-4)      at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877)
18:42:12,774 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-4)      at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:671)
18:42:12,774 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-4)      at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:930)
18:42:12,775 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-4)      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

xhtml is:

```
<h:form id="frmItemsPage">
   <p:panel id="tblPanel">
        <p:dataTable widgetVar="TbItems" id="tbItemsList" var="row"
                value="#{unavailableItems.itemsModel}" scrollable="true"
                scrollRows="20"
                liveScroll="true" rowKey="#{row.upId}"
                lazy="true"
                scrollHeight="500" style="width:98%; margin:0 auto;"
                emptyMessage="No Items." editable="true" editMode="cell"  resizableColumns="true"
                rowIndexVar="rowIndex">
        <p:ajax event="cellEdit" listener="#{unavailableItems.onCellEdit2}" />
        <p:column width="12" style="text-align:right;">
            <f:facet name="header">
                <h:outputText id="codeLabel" value="Item Code" />
            </f:facet>
            <h:outputText id="itemCode" value="#{row.itemCode}">
        </h:outputText>
        </p:column>                                 
        <p:column headerText="Description"  width="115">
          <p:cellEditor>
              <f:facet name="output"><h:outputText id="desOutpt" value="#{row.description}" /> 
              </f:facet>
              <f:facet name="input">
                     <p:selectOneMenu id="desciprtion" value="#{row.description}"
                        required="false" style="width:185px;">
                      <f:selectItems value="#{unavailableItems.descriptions}" />
                     </p:selectOneMenu>
               </f:facet>   
          </p:cellEditor>   
        </p:column>
        <f:facet name="footer"></f:facet>
        </p:dataTable>
                        
    </p:panel>
 </h:form>
```

and my bean is:

```
@ManagedBean(name = "unavailableItems")
@ViewScoped
public class UnavailableItemsBean implements Serializable {
    
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private List<String> descriptionsStrings;
    private List<SelectItem> descriptions;
    
    private LazyDataModel<Item> itemsModel;

    
    public UnavailableAssetsPageBean() {
        this.loadItems();
        this.setDescriptionsStrings(DescriptionDAO.getInstance().getAllDescriptions());
    }

    public void loadItems() {
        
            this.itemsModel = new LazyDataModel<Item>() {
                private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

                @Override
                public List<Item> load(int first, int pageSize, String sortField, SortOrder sortOrder,
                        Map<String, Object> filters) {

                    List<Item> items = ItemDAO.getInstance().getUnavailableItems(first,
                            pageSize + first);
                    int totalRecords = ItemDAO.getInstance().getUnavailableItemsCount();

                    itemsModel.setRowCount(totalRecords);
                    RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().update("frmItemsPage:tbItemsList");
                    return items;
                }
            };
        
        
    }
    public void onCellEdit2(CellEditEvent event) {
        DataTable dataTable = (DataTable) event.getSource();
        Item item = (Item) dataTable.getRowData();
        Object oldValue = event.getOldValue();
        Object newValue = event.getNewValue();
        System.out.println("old value: "+oldValue);
        System.out.println("new value: "+newValue);
    }
    
    public List<SelectItem> getDescriptions() {
        setDescriptions();
        return descriptions;
    }

    public void setDescriptions() {
        descriptions = new ArrayList<SelectItem>();
        descriptions.add(new SelectItem("", ""));
        for (String des : descriptionsStrings) {
            descriptions.add(new SelectItem(des, des));
        }
    }

    
    public List<String> getDescriptionsStrings() {
        return descriptionsStrings;
    }

    public void setDescriptionsStrings(List<String> descriptionsStrings) {
        this.descriptionsStrings = descriptionsStrings;
    }

    public LazyDataModel<Item> getItemsModel() {
        return itemsModel;
    }

    public void setItemsModel(LazyDataModel<Item> itemsModel) {
        this.itemsModel = itemsModel;
    }
    
}
```

the error sometimes also appears while scrolling (live scroll). I am using primefaces 5.3, JSF 2.0.4, JBoss AS-7.1.1.Final

Comment: You tagged it mojarra, so you checked that it only fails with mojarra and not with myfaces (tags are for what is playing an explicit role in the problem, not for what you use). Checked newer JBoss (with newer JSF?) or a newer PrimeFaces (and its release notes)? Please do. We do not want to chase things solved in newer versions.

Comment: limitation is I can't update primefaces and jboss. I tried with jsf 2.1.0 and 2.2.0 but the problem is there

Comment: It's indeed a bug in Mojarra. Upgrade it.

Comment: can you tell me on which version should I upgrade?

Comment: upgrading jsf is still not working

Comment: I narrowed the problem is with <p:cellEditor>. if I remove it and use plain text then it works fine