# javax.validation.UnexpectedTypeException: HV000030: No validator could be found for type: java.lang.Integer

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, bean-validation, data-conversion

I have to take input for `paper_name` and `date_of_birth` as `int` and `date` datatype respectively from a form.

Below is the code:

```
<li> Number:<input type="text" name="paper_number" ></li>
< li>date of birth: <input type="text" name="date_of_birth"></ li>
```

I have `paperNumber` and `dateOfBirth` variable in the controller as int and Date datatypes respectively.

Please help me change the datatype of paper_number and date_of_birth from string to int and date respectively.

I have seen other answers on stackoverflow and they have used jstl for the same but I am not able to figure out how to apply it here.

Controller code:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/student" , params = "add", method = RequestMethod.POST )
       public String postAddStudent(
                   @RequestParam("date_of_birth" ) Date date,
                   @RequestParam("paper_number" ) int paperNumber)
```

Below is the EntityClass

```
public class EntityClass extends BaseEntity {

@Column(name = "DATE_OF_BIRTH", nullable = false)
    @NotBlank
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd-mm-yyyy")
    private Date dateOfBirth;//TODO

    @Column(name = "PAPER_NUMBER")
    private short paperNumber;
..

}
```

Below is the log

```
description The server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is javax.validation.UnexpectedTypeException: HV000030: No validator could be found for type: java.lang.Integer.
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:894)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:789)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter.java:113)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
root cause

javax.validation.UnexpectedTypeException: HV000030: No validator could be found for type: java.lang.Integer.
    org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ConstraintTree.verifyResolveWasUnique(ConstraintTree.java:394)
    org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ConstraintTree.findMatchingValidatorClass(ConstraintTree.java:375)
    org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ConstraintTree.getInitializedValidator(ConstraintTree.java:333)
    org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ConstraintTree.validateConstraints(ConstraintTree.java:155)
    org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ConstraintTree.validateConstraints(ConstraintTree.java:125)
    org.hibernate.validator.internal.metadata.core.MetaConstraint.validateConstraint(MetaConstraint.java:86)
    org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateConstraint(ValidatorImpl.java:442)
    org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateConstraintsForDefaultGroup(ValidatorImpl.java:387)
    org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateConstraintsForCurrentGroup(ValidatorImpl.java:351)
    org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateInContext(ValidatorImpl.java:303)
    org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validate(ValidatorImpl.java:133)
    org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.BeanValidationEventListener.validate(BeanValidationEventListener.java:136)
    org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.BeanValidationEventListener.onPreInsert(BeanValidationEventListener.java:94)
    org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityIdentityInsertAction.preInsert(EntityIdentityInsertAction.java:178)
    org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityIdentityInsertAction.execute(EntityIdentityInsertAction.java:75)
    org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:362)
    org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addResolvedEntityInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:203)
    org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:183)
    org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addAction(ActionQueue.java:167)
    org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.addInsertAction(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:320)
    org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:287)
    org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:193)
    org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:126)
    org.hibernate.ejb.event.EJB3MergeEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(EJB3MergeEventListener.java:71)
    org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.saveTransientEntity(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:236)
    org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:216)
    org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.onMerge(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:154)
    org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireMerge(SessionImpl.java:910)
    org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.merge(SessionImpl.java:892)
    org.hibernate.engine.spi.CascadingAction$6.cascade(CascadingAction.java:288)
    org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeToOne(Cascade.java:380)
    org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:323)
    org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:208)
    org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascade(Cascade.java:165)
    org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.cascadeBeforeSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:423)
    org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:213)
    org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.onMerge(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:154)
    org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.onMerge(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:76)
    org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireMerge(SessionImpl.java:900)
    org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.merge(SessionImpl.java:884)
    org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.merge(SessionImpl.java:888)
    org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.merge(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:879)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:365)
    com.sun.proxy.$Proxy41.merge(Unknown Source)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:240)
    com.sun.proxy.$Proxy41.merge(Unknown Source)
    org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.save(SimpleJpaRepository.java:329)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.executeMethodOn(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:368)
    org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:349)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:110)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:155)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
    com.sun.proxy.$Proxy53.save(Unknown Source)
    in.ac.jmi.controllers.AdminController.postAddStudent(AdminController.java:262)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:213)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:126)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:96)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:617)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:578)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:923)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:789)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter.java:113)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
```

Comment: Are you using hibernate as ORM?

Comment: yes, added the code for the same.

Comment: See my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35792351/input-integer-and-date-data-type-from-jsp/#35793103)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Hope you're using validation in hibernate like this,

```
@NotBlank
private Date some;
```

`@NotBlank` is for String type. There is no concept of `java.util.Date` being blank. It can be null or not null.. Use `@NotNull` instead,

```
@NotNull
@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd-mm-yyyy")
private Date dateOfBirth;
```

See [Balus answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17074611/javax-servlet-servletexception-hv000030-no-validator-could-be-found-for-type) and [@NotBlank](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/4.1/api/org/hibernate/validator/constraints/NotBlank.html) for more details.

**Update**

> HTTP Status 400: The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect.

For the above error in Date type try add `@DateTimeFormat` annotation and mention the format of date you giving as input (say `yyyy-mm-dd`). Like below,

```
@RequestMapping(value="/fetch" , method=RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody String fetchResult(@RequestParam("from")   @DateTimeFormat(pattern="yyyy-MM-dd") Date fromDate) {
    //Content goes here
}
```

Comment: i have removed all the hibernate validations. and now it says "
description: The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect ()."

Comment: Instead of `Date` and `int` type try with `String` type. The issue is controller not getting the value's as expected type.

Comment: yeah with string it's working..!, but I have to use int and date in the form itself.

Comment: Use `@ModelAttribute` parameter, If you're binding a request parameter to a field. See [Reference](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-typeconversion)

Comment: can you please provide an example for the above. (for int the problem is solved) now remains date datatype only.

Comment: See my answer update, since the date field is the only issue try with `@DateTimeFormat` annotation. It will work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105366/discussion-between-md-faisal-and-vinoth-krishnan).

Comment: It worked, i was entering the date field like "1991-02-08" instead of "1991/02/08" in my jsp form, when I changed the input to later, the Controller accepted it. Thank you for your time @Vinoth

Answer (score 0):

well if you are not using any framework like spring mvc or controller , then  you have to do it your self. Request parameter is always sent as string to server side. Now whether some frame work can do it before request arrives into your controller as part of your interceptor. Otherwise you have to do it manually after getting `request.getParameter("param_name")`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to restrict the input that is entered by the user, you will have to use Javascript to restrict the input type (You can use jQuery validator plugin for this).

Or else, if you want to convert the input entered by the user to integer and date, in your form action (servlet, perhaps), you will need to parse the integer using

```
Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("integer_field_name"));
```

as for Date, use SimpleDateFormat API.

References:

1. [How to convert String to Date](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-convert-string-to-date-java/)
2. [jQuery validator plugin](http://jqueryvalidation.org/documentation/)

Comment: yeah that can be done but it would be better if jsp would do it for me.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, but what I suspect is `private short paperNumber;` is the problem.. The request mapping is mapping the same to Integer, Not sure how downgrading Integer to small int works in hibernate.