# error: HV000030:No validator could be found for type

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am using Spring MVC and Spring Security and hibernate. I have checked the google for all possible solution, yet i can finding the solution.

**why do I keep getting the following error?**

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcher] in context with path [/Jupiter_M] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is javax.validation.UnexpectedTypeException: HV000030: No validator could be found for type: java.lang.Integer.] with root cause
javax.validation.UnexpectedTypeException: HV000030: No validator could be found for type: java.lang.Integer.
```

full Error stack

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcher] in context with path [/Jupiter_M] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is javax.validation.UnexpectedTypeException: HV000030: No validator could be found for type: java.lang.Integer.] with root cause
javax.validation.UnexpectedTypeException: HV000030: No validator could be found for type: java.lang.Integer.
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation.ConstraintValidatorManager.verifyResolveWasUnique(ConstraintValidatorManager.java:218)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation.ConstraintValidatorManager.findMatchingValidatorClass(ConstraintValidatorManager.java:193)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation.ConstraintValidatorManager.getInitializedValidator(ConstraintValidatorManager.java:97)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation.ConstraintTree.validateConstraints(ConstraintTree.java:125)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation.ConstraintTree.validateComposingConstraints(ConstraintTree.java:233)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation.ConstraintTree.validateConstraints(ConstraintTree.java:102)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation.ConstraintTree.validateConstraints(ConstraintTree.java:91)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.metadata.core.MetaConstraint.validateConstraint(MetaConstraint.java:83)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateConstraint(ValidatorImpl.java:547)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateConstraintsForDefaultGroup(ValidatorImpl.java:487)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateConstraintsForCurrentGroup(ValidatorImpl.java:451)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateInContext(ValidatorImpl.java:403)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validate(ValidatorImpl.java:206)
    at org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.SpringValidatorAdapter.validate(SpringValidatorAdapter.java:108)
    at org.springframework.validation.DataBinder.validate(DataBinder.java:866)
    at org.springframework.web.method.annotation.ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.validateIfApplicable(ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.java:164)
    at org.springframework.web.method.annotation.ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.resolveArgument(ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.java:111)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:99)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:161)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:128)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:817)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:731)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:968)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:870)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:650)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:844)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:316)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:126)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:90)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:114)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:122)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.java:157)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:169)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:48)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:205)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:120)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:120)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:64)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:91)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:53)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:213)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:176)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:218)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:956)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:442)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1082)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:623)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

This this my Model:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Users")
public class UsersInfo implements Serializable {


    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer idUsers;


    @Size(min=3, max=30)
    @Column(name="FIRST_NAME", nullable=false)
    private String First_Name;


    @Size(min=3, max=30)
    @Column(name="LAST_NAME", nullable=false)
    private String Last_Name;

    @NotEmpty
    @Column(name="ADDRESS", nullable=false)
    private String Address;

    @NotEmpty
    @Column(name="PHONE_NUMBER", nullable=false)
    private Integer Phone_Number;

    @NotEmpty @Email
    @Column(name="EMAIL", nullable=false)
    private String email;

    @NotEmpty
    @Column(name="USERNAME", unique=true, nullable=false)
    private String UserName;


    @Column(name="PASSWORD", nullable=false)
    @Size(min=6, max=25)
    private String Password = null;
    /*
    @NotEmpty
    @Transient
    @Size(min=8, max=25)
    private String retypePassword = null;
    */


    @DateTimeFormat(pattern="dd/MM/yyyy")
    @Past @NotNull
    @Column(name="DATE_OF_BIRTH", nullable=false)
    private Date Date_of_Birth;

    @NotEmpty
    @Column(name="STATE", nullable=false)
    private String state=State.ACTIVE.getState();   

    @NotEmpty
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name = "User_Roles_Match",
    joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "USERSID") }, 
    inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "USER_ROLE_ID") })
    private Set<URoles> userRoles = new HashSet<URoles>();
```

Massage properties:

```
Size.userInfo.First_Name=First Name must be between {2} and {1} characters long
Size.userInfo.Last_Name=Last Name must be between {2} and {1} characters long
NotNull.userInfo.Date_of_Birth=Date of birth can not be blank
Past.userInfo.Date_of_Birth=Date of birth must be in the past
NotEmpty.userInfo.Address=Address can not be blank
NotEmpty.userInfo.email=Email can not be blank.
NotEmpty.userInfo.Phone_Number= Cell Number cannot be blank
Size.userInfo.Password=Password must be between{5}.and{1} characters long
NotEmpty.userInfo.retypePassword = Confirm password is required!
notmatch.userInfo.Password = Password and Conform password is not match!
NotEmpty.userInfo.UserName=User name can not be blank.
NotEmpty.userInfo.URoles=At least one profile must be selected.
non.unique.UserName=User Name  {0} already exist. Please fill in different value.
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17074611/javax-servlet-servletexception-hv000030-no-validator-could-be-found-for-type Use NotNull rather than NotEmpty annotation for the phone number

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have defined incorrect validation,

```
@NotEmpty
@Column(name="PHONE_NUMBER", nullable=false)
private Integer Phone_Number;
```

It should be,

```
@NotNull
@Column(name="PHONE_NUMBER", nullable=false)
private Integer Phone_Number;
```

`@NotEmpty` is basically for collections, string and arrays and not for Integer or any Wrappers. You need to define `@NotNull` to check for null validation on Wrapper data type fields.

Please refer documentation : http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/4.2/api/org/hibernate/validator/constraints/NotEmpty.html