# Bean validation with Spring and Hibernate doesn't work

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, validation, spring-mvc

I'm trying to validate this bean:

```
public class NewUserCompanyForm implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 6414340627544822204L;

@Email(groups = ValidationGroup1.class)
@NotBlank(groups = ValidationGroup1.class)
@Length(min = 5)
private String userName;

@NotBlank(groups = ValidationGroup1.class)
private String password;

@NotBlank(groups = ValidationGroup1.class)
private String repeatedPassword;

@NotBlank(groups = ValidationGroup2.class)
private String companyName;

@Pattern(regexp = "\\d\\d-\\d\\d\\d", groups = ValidationGroup2.class)
private String postalCode;

@NotBlank(groups = ValidationGroup2.class)
@Pattern(regexp = "\\p{L}*", groups = ValidationGroup2.class)
private String city;

@Pattern(regexp = "[-A-Za-z0-9 ,.]*", groups = ValidationGroup2.class)
@NotBlank(groups = ValidationGroup2.class)
private String addressDetails;
```

Unfortunately I'm getting exceptions for almost all field validations:

```
javax.validation.UnexpectedTypeException: HV000030: No validator could be found for constraint 'javax.validation.constraints.Email' validating type 'java.lang.String'. Check configuration for 'userName'
```

It is always `UnexpectedTypeException: HV000030`. I read the documentation of Hibernate and Spring validation and everything seems to be OK, since e.g. `@Email` annotation can be used with Strings.

EDIT: added pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    <thymeleaf.spring.version>3.0.7.RC1</thymeleaf.spring.version>
    <thymeleaf.version>3.0.7.RELEASE</thymeleaf.version>
    <hibernate.validation.version>6.0.2.Final</hibernate.validation.version>
    <hibernate.version>5.2.11.Final</hibernate.version>
    <hibernate.commons.version>5.0.1.Final</hibernate.commons.version>
    <bean.validation.api.version>2.0.0.Final</bean.validation.api.version>
    <mysql.connector.java.version>6.0.6</mysql.connector.java.version>
    <spring.version>5.0.0.RELEASE</spring.version>
    <spring.session.version>1.3.1.RELEASE</spring.session.version>
    <spring.security.version>4.2.3.RELEASE</spring.security.version>
    <spring.webflow.version>2.4.6.RELEASE</spring.webflow.version>
    <spring.boot.test.version>2.0.0.M5</spring.boot.test.version>
    <common.codecs>1.10</common.codecs>
</properties>

<groupId>pwr.groupproject.vouchers</groupId>
<artifactId>voucherApp</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.7.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.session</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-session-jdbc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-test -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.session</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-session</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.session.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.thymeleaf/thymeleaf-spring5 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
        <artifactId>thymeleaf-spring5</artifactId>
        <version>${thymeleaf.spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate.validator/hibernate-validator -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.validation.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.validation/validation-api -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
        <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        <version>${bean.validation.api.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>${mysql.connector.java.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.thymeleaf/thymeleaf -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
        <artifactId>thymeleaf</artifactId>
        <version>${thymeleaf.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-orm -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-context -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate.javax.persistence/hibernate-jpa-2.1-api -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate.common/hibernate-commons-annotations -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.common</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.commons.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-codec/commons-codec -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
        <version>${common.codecs}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.webflow</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webflow</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.webflow.version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<repositories>
</repositories>
```

Here is the class being used to test the validation:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {SpringWebFlowConfiguration.class, WebConfiguration.class})
public class NewUserCompanyFormValidationTest {
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("localValidatorFactoryBean")
    private LocalValidatorFactoryBean validator;
    @Autowired
    private MessageSource messageSource;

    @Test
    public void DependencyInjectionTest(){
        Assert.assertNotNull(validator);
    }

    @Test
    public void NewUserCompanyFormValidatingTest(){
        NewUserCompanyForm form1=new NewUserCompanyForm();
        form1.setPassword("");
        form1.setUserName("");
        form1.setRepeatedPassword("");
        Set<ConstraintViolation<NewUserCompanyForm>> volations1=validator.validate(form1,NewUserCompanyForm.ValidationGroup1.class);

    }
}
```

Comment: have you looked in your project (or inside the spring/hibernate validation jar) if you there is a messages.properties and within it a key "javax.validation.constraints.Email" because that is what the error is complaining about

Comment: No, there is no such key in the message.properties file. Adding it there manually doesn't help.

Comment: Could you please provide additional code and/or config (e.g. minimal `pom.xml`) in order to make it easier to reproduce your issue? I've used bean validation before but within a full Spring + Jersey web application. I'd like to reproduce your issue with less effort than that - if possible. :)

Comment: Thanks for the `pom.xml`. Could you also provide code which makes use of a `NewCompanyUserForm` and validates it? I'll have a try (later -
 heading out right now) at programmatic validation of `NewCompanyUserForm` using something like what is done at http://www.baeldung.com/javax-validation later this weekend.

Comment: Can you show the code for this class `ValidationGroup1` ?

Comment: It's an empty interface used only for webflow validation-hints.

Answer (score 0):

Based on a read of https://stackoverflow.com/a/17086477/1840078 I surmise that the issue is redundant and possibly conflicting bean validation annotations.  When an `@Email` annotation is present a `@NotBlank` annotation is redundant and chances are the `@Length` annotation is also redundant.  A valid email address cannot be blank and must have length of at least 5 for an email host with a top-level domain in its fully qualified hostname.

Comment: I tried leaving just an @Email annotation. Unfortunately, it didn't solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out...

The @Email annotation hasn't a @Constraint (line 36)

```
@Constraint(validatedBy = { })
```

In validation-api-2.0.1.Final, so the final result is `javax.servlet.ServletException: HV000030: No validator could be found for constraint 'javax.validation.constraints.Email'`